# Action Not Firing after Orgin transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, action, hittest

I have my UITableViewCell set up so that you can swipe right to show actions, then again swipe left to hide them. they are set offscreen, and when the cell is swiped the cells orgin is transitioned left -120px to reveal the controls.

The problem is that they are not firing once revealed, and clicked on. Here is my code.

**Setting up my cell**

```
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *completeSwipeGestureShow = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showCompleteControl:)];
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *completeSwipeGestureHide = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideCompleteControl:)];

        completeSwipeGestureShow.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        completeSwipeGestureHide.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

        UIView *cellControlDone = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-60, 0, 60, 127)];
        UIView *cellControlDelete = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-120, 0, 60, 127)];

        cellControlDone.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(36.0/255.0) green:(195.0/255.0) blue:(28.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        cellControlDelete.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(236.0/255.0) green:(1.0/255.0) blue:(1.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

        UIButton *cellControlDoneIcon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIButton *cellControlDeleteIcon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [cellControlDoneIcon setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Done.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cellControlDeleteIcon setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        cellControlDoneIcon.frame = CGRectMake(((60 - 22) / 2), ((127 - 22) / 2), 22, 22);
        cellControlDeleteIcon.frame = CGRectMake(((60 - 22) / 2), ((127 - 22) / 2), 22, 22);

        [cellControlDoneIcon addTarget:self action:@selector(completeTask) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cellControlDeleteIcon addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelTask) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cellControlDone addSubview:cellControlDoneIcon];
        [cellControlDelete addSubview:cellControlDeleteIcon];

        [cell addSubview:cellControlDone];
        [cell addSubview:cellControlDelete];

        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

        [cell addGestureRecognizer:completeSwipeGestureShow];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:completeSwipeGestureHide];
```

**The Actions**

```
- (void) showCompleteControl:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
        delay:0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
        animations:^{
            [swipedCell setBounds:CGRectMake(-120, 0, 320, 127)];
            NSArray* subviews = [swipedCell.contentView subviews];
            for (UIView* subview in subviews) {
                if(subview.tag == 9999)
                {
                    subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 126, 10, 1);
                    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(224.0/255.0) green:(224.0/255.0) blue:(224.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
                }
            }
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            // Do nothing
        }
     ];
}

- (void) hideCompleteControl:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
        delay:0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
        animations:^{
            [swipedCell setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 127)];
            NSArray* subviews = [swipedCell.contentView subviews];
            for (UIView* subview in subviews) {
                if(subview.tag == 9999)
                {
                    subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 127);
                    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(124.0/255.0) green:(124.0/255.0) blue:(124.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
                }
            }
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            // Do nothing
        }
     ];
}

- (void) completeTask
{
    NSLog(@"Task Complete");
}

- (void) cancelTask
{
    NSLog(@"Task Canceled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it could be this...

Since you are moving the cell by adjusting its bounds, that means its frame is still in the same place and only the content is moving aside. So the touches are still being blocked from the revealed-controls because they are still within the cell's frame and it is handling them.